# performing ccf on time series- univariate problems

Tags: r, time-series

I have two xts objects, rest and awake.

I want to cross correlate them, so I do

```
ccf(rest, awake)
```

But I get the message

```
Error in ccf(rest, awake) : univariate time series only
```

awake looks like this but 264 rows.

```
2017-01-01 07:50:00    94.44444
2017-01-02 08:05:00    95.43147
```

rest is similar, with 264 rows.

```
2017-01-01    57
2017-01-02    58
```

Why is it throwing this error?  I've tried removing the hours/minutes/seconds from awake, but that doesn't work either.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the output indicates. `ccf()` expects two univariate time-series (numeric vectors) ie. you need to convert your `xts` time-series first:

```
library(xts)
x <- xts(rnorm(100), seq(as.Date("2017-01-01"), length.out = 100, by = 1))
y <- xts(rnorm(100), seq(as.Date("2017-01-01"), length.out = 100, by = 1))
ccf(x[, 1, drop = TRUE], y[, 1, drop = TRUE]) #one way
ccf(as.numeric(x), as.numeric(y)) #another way
```